# Deviation from expected output with NSString to NSDate conversion using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using the below method to convert a NSString to NSDate.

Always when I construct the NSDate from String, the date is one day behind the current day I have provided as part of the input and hour is 18:30:00 +0000. Why this deviation from what I have provided. I was expecting to have the same date what I have provided and hour as 00:00:00 +0000

```
+(NSDate*)convertStringToNSDate:(NSString*)string withFormat:(NSString*)format{

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:format];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];  
    [dateFormat release];
    return date;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up quite regularly but I could not find a suitable duplicate (searching on the phone does not help).

NSDate represents a specific point in time. When you log the value of an NSDate it is displayed in GMT, which is 5.5 hours behind your timezone (India, I assume). So the value is correct. If you run that date back through your date formatter you will get the local time of midnight again, since the date formatter is using your local time zone.